# boost spirit dynamic lexer with column numbers?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, lexer

I'm having trouble making a dynamic boost spirit lexer that tracks the column number. Is this possible? Can anyone provide a simple example?

Thanks!

Comment: which version of boost ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post

[How to use Boost::Spirit::Lex to lex a file without reading the whole file into memory first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715829/how-to-use-boostspiritlex-to-lex-a-file-without-reading-the-whole-file-into/4719117#4719117)

And

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/wave/doc/samples.html

Answer (score 0):

http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/tracking-the-input-position-while-parsing/

The code they reference throughout the article is posted at the end.

Comment: That's for `boost::spirit::qi`, not for `boost::spirit::lex`.